# Cannot use object of type PDOException as array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i'm currently finishing my website and all the stuff works just fine 
but i keep getting a error. It don't break anything but it's annoying to see.
I have been trying alot of stuff but i need some new eyes on this problem :/

**Error**

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type PDOException as array in
>   /home/thecodin/public_html/memberlist.php on line 114

**Code**

```
Line 113: foreach($MemberList as $MemberListEach) {
Line 114: $MemberGroup = $MemberListEach['Group'];
Line 115: $MemberListGroup = $Class_Users->group_info($MemberGroup);
```

**Database Structure**

http://gyazo.com/785f780e6b62df6136087070d7c69c65

**Member List Class**

```
public function Member_List($offset, $max)
{
    try
    {

        // Run Query - Member List
        $member_list = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Users` ORDER BY `Group` DESC LIMIT ".$offset.",".$max."");
        $member_list->execute();

        $member_list_fetch = $member_list->fetchAll();

        return $member_list_fetch;

    } catch(PDOException $e) {

        return array("ERROR", $e);

    }   
}
```

**Group Info Class**

```
public function group_info($id)
{
    try
    {
        // Run Query - Group Info
        $group_info = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `Groups` WHERE `GID`=:id");
        $group_info->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $group_info->execute();
        $group_info_rows = $group_info->fetch();
        return $group_info_rows;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
            return array("ERROR", $e);
    }   
}
```

Comment: You will have to provide more code than just that.

Comment: Nothing above shows you instantiating the PDOException class. Where is that code?

Comment: `$MemberListEach` is a PDOException. try `var_dump($MemberListEach);` to see the error.

Comment: The `$e` assigned from the exception is an **object**, then in your foreach you treat as an array, its as simple as that... you should check for ERROR before doing the foreach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.

I just had to change the return to a string insted of an array in the PDOException
like Loz Cherone said.

I hope i'm done this right.

Answer (score 0):

```
"/home/thecodin/public_html/memberlist.php on line 114"
```

line 114 - `$MemberListEach['Group']; /* this is array use... */`

try dumping object with `var_dump`